# firebase-functions@0.7.5 requires a peer of firebase-admin@~5.5.0 but none is installed?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

[Here is the error pic and please also tell me how to commit that file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F2skF.png)

Comment: its a warning, not an error

Comment: ok but i solved it

Comment: How did you solve it @Nikhil?

Comment: how did you solve it?

Comment: guys answer is below

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This warning means that the same versions are required in your warning message like in my case it was

*firebase-functions@0.7.5 requires a peer of firebase-admin@~5.5.0 but none is installed?*

so this signify that i was using a greater version of firebase admin but the firebase-functions required 5.5.0 ver of firebase-admin

so to resolve it type in the following code: *npm install firebase-admin@5.5.0*
where in you have to replace that ver "5.5.0" based on your required ver.

Like in your warning if it shows

*firebase-admin@~4.5.0 but none is installed?*

then you have to replace the ver as

*npm install firebase-admin@4.5.0*

Answer (score 4):

I solved it by typing:

```
npm install firebase-admin@5.5.0
```

Answer (score 0):

here it was just another version ...

> firebase-functions@0.8.1 requires a peer of firebase-admin@~5.8.1 but none was installed.

while instead of manually installing packages, one can add dependencies to the `package.json`:

```
{
    ...
    "dependencies": {
        "firebase-admin": "~5.8.1",
        "firebase-functions": "^0.8.1"
    }
}
```

and then download them altogether by running `npm install .` in the project directory. there are more libraries available at [@firebase-ops](https://www.npmjs.com/~firebase-ops) on npmjs.com (this is where I have the numbers from).

`sudo npm install -g firebase-tools` installs the `firebase` command, to test & deploy.

Answer (score 0):

I solved mine my using the following command:

npm install firebase-admin --save